# Check if file exist in folder javascript .ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried using the code below but it only works if i am checking for file in the root folder (e.g. url: "filename.html")... If i want to check for files that are in folders (e.g. url: "folder/filename.html") like the code below, it will always success and alert me "File found" even when the folder is empty or the folder doesn't have that file.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "folder/filename.html",
    cache: false,
    success: function () {
            alert("File found");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            if (xhr.status == 404) {
                    alert("xhr: File Not Found");
    }
    alert("Error: File Not Found");
    }
});
```

Comment: If you look at the request with Fiddler/firebug/chrome debugger, that is returned from your server?

Comment: The request from firebug shows that the file has been found under folder/filename.html... when the file doesn't exist in the folder

Comment: Can you give us a look at your file structure and code a bit more? Also, what browser are you using? Setting this up exactly as you've shown works for me in latest Chrome, Safari and Firefox on a Mac.

Comment: Ah sorry about it, abit dumb for this prob...... When i check for the file, the folder is actually restricted so it redirect me to another page, which the code return me the file found is actually the redirected page instead for the file im actually looking for....

Does any1 of you know how to check for file exist in restricted folders?

Sorry about the silly mistake and I sincerely thanks for your time and effort.